# Adobe Illustrator 5: When I move an object right it moves up?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac

I have Adobe Illustrator 5 on Mac. Everything was normal before but now some document level transformation settings have changed.

Arrow keys don't work as they should. When I move selected object right it moves up and same different behavior for other keys.

When I write text it's by default 90 degrees.

Any idea which option has messed things up?

Answer (score 2):

Set "Constrain Angle" to 0 in "Preferences->General".